# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float' - after converting to float

Tags: python, typeerror

I know that this question has been asked numerous times but I am still unable to find the issue in my code. My program is a grade calculator. After inputting the grades I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Jeremy/Documents/Python Projects/Mosier_Jeremy_HW4.py", line 59, in <module>
    main ()
  File "/Users/Jeremy/Documents/Python Projects/Mosier_Jeremy_HW4.py", line 53, in main
    total = calcTotal (entry_exam1, entry_exam2, entry_exam3, entry_hw, entry_lqr, entry_fp)
  File "/Users/Jeremy/Documents/Python Projects/Mosier_Jeremy_HW4.py", line 29, in calcTotal
    total = float ((exam1 * EXAM1_WEIGHT) + (exam2 * EXAM2_WEIGHT) + (exam3 * EXAM3_WEIGHT) + (hw * HW_WEIGHT) + (lqr * LQR_WEIGHT) + (fp * FP_WEIGHT))
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Here is my code:

```
EXAM1_WEIGHT = .2
EXAM2_WEIGHT = .2
EXAM3_WEIGHT = .2
HW_WEIGHT = .2
LQR_WEIGHT = .1
FP_WEIGHT = .1

def entry_validation (assignment) :
    entry = -1

    while entry == -1:
        entry = input ('What was your final score for ' + assignment + '? ')

        if entry == '':
            entry = -1
            print ('ERROR: You cannot leave this field blank. Please try again.')

        else:
            entry = float (entry)

            if entry < 0 or entry > 100:
                entry = -1
                print ('ERROR: You score must be between 0 and 100. Please try again.')

    return assignment


def calcTotal (exam1, exam2, exam3, hw, lqr, fp) :
    total = float ((exam1 * EXAM1_WEIGHT) + (exam2 * EXAM2_WEIGHT) + (exam3 * EXAM3_WEIGHT) + (hw * HW_WEIGHT) + (lqr * LQR_WEIGHT) + (fp * FP_WEIGHT))

    return total

def calcLetter (total) :
    if total < 89.5:
        return 'A'
    elif total < 79.5:
        return 'B'
    elif total < 69.5:
        return 'C'
    elif total < 59.5:
        return 'D'
    else:
        return 'F'

def main () :
    entry_exam1 = entry_validation ('Exam 1')
    entry_exam2 = entry_validation ('Exam 2')
    entry_exam3 = entry_validation ('Exam 3')
    entry_hw = entry_validation ('Homework')
    entry_lqr = entry_validation ('Language Quick Reference')
    entry_fp = entry_validation ('Final Project')

    total = calcTotal (entry_exam1, entry_exam2, entry_exam3, entry_hw, entry_lqr, entry_fp)
    letter = calcLetter (total)

    print ('Your total score is a(n): ', format (total, ',.2%'))
    print ('Your final letter grade is a(n): ', letter)

main ()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code I assume that you want `entry_validation` to return a float, but it is actually returning the string you provide when calling it.

For example, in:

```
entry_exam1 = entry_validation ('Exam 1')
```

`entry_validation ('Exam 1')` will return the string `Exam 1`. If you try to multiply a string by any float, you get the `TypeError` you reported.

You will have to modify you `entry_validation` function, so that it returns a float:

```
def entry_validation (assignment) :
    entry = -1

    while entry == -1:
        entry = input ('What was your final score for ' + assignment + '? ')

        if entry == '':
            entry = -1
            print ('ERROR: You cannot leave this field blank. Please try again.')

        else:
            # Let's handle possible exceptions when the input cannot be converted
            try:
                entry = float (entry)
                if entry < 0 or entry > 100:
                     entry = -1
                     print ('ERROR: You score must be between 0 and 100. Please try again.')
                else:
                     return entry
            except ValueError:
                entry = -1
                print("ERROR: Must be a float")
```

Comment: Thank you! That was the issue. Program works great now.